# How to import class from python module (boost.python)?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have a python function:

```
def log(text):
    print text
```

saved in `Callbacks.py` file. Now I want to import it to c++ function and execute. This works fine:

```
py_fun = import("Callbacks");
py_fun.attr("log")(text);
```

But I would like to make `log` function part of a class:

```
class Logger:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_read = -1

    def log(self, text):
        print text
```

How can I import it to C++ and create an instance of `Logger`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the way you'd think:

```
py::object mod = py::import("Callbacks");
py::object logger = mod.attr("Logger")();
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. i knew I was missing something. And I was missing parentheses.